# qt designer slot casting

Tags: qt, signals-slots, designer

I'm trying to connect a QDial::valueChanged signal to a QLabel::setNum slot in Qt Designer.
The problem is that there are 2 overload for QLabel::setNum. I'm getting the unresolved overloaded function type error.
I know that I need to cast the slot, but this is in ui_mainwindow.h. So it is generated.

How can I force it to use the proper cast when it generates the code ?

thanks.

Comment: `How can I force it to use the proper cast when it generates the code ?` - you can't, you have to do it in c++

Comment: so I have to create a slot in mainwindow and redirect the signal to the proper slot on the qlabel.   Weird that they have not thought of this in designer!

Comment: The signal slot editing functionality is not for complex stuff - it was added a long time ago but is not really the way to go nowadays. Also I don't see the need to create an extra slot in mainwindow though.

Comment: what is "the way" (I'm not a mandalorian ;) ).  Is designer still "popular" these days (I'm new to qt).   And I was thinking of creating the extra slot in mainwindow so that I can connect the QDial::valueChanged to it, and from there call the QLabel::setNum.

Comment: connect(dial, &QDial::valueChanged, label, [label](int val) { label->setValue(val); });